# How to create function and return a date format out of digits

Tags: plsql

How can I proceed if I would like to write a function get_date which is receiving the date code and returns a date on the form 'YYYY-MM-DD' if for example a company sends a 4-digit date code in their text files: for example, 1234, where 1 represents the year 2001, and 234 represents the day No 234 in 2001?

Comment: I would think more information is needed about possible values. For example, will your data set only include values for years between 2001-2009? Or could it have 2016? And if it does, would that be 6234 or 16234? Please elaborate.

Comment: What is "a date on the form 'YYYY-MM-DD"? Did you mean a string representing a date, or an actual date? (In which case it has no "form".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you receive code in 5 digit 2 digit is year and next 3 digit is day number

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION date_format(
      input NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS
    my_date VARCHAR2(22);
  BEGIN
    SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date(input,'rrddd'),'yyyy-MM-DD') INTO my_date FROM dual;
    RETURN my_date ;
  END;
```

Function created.

```
select date_format(12111) from dual;
```

### DATE_FORMAT(12111)

2012-04-20

Answer (score 1):

Simply use built-in `TO_DATE` function.
If you deep into the documentation, you will find this:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#g195443

```
+---------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Element | Specify in TO_*     | Description                                                                  |
|         | datetime functions? |                                                                              |
+---------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DDD     | Yes                 | Day of year (1-366).                                                         |
+---------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| RR      | Yes                 | Lets you store 20th century dates in the 21st century using only two digits. |
|         |                     | See Also: Additional discussion on RR datetime format element                |
|         |                     | in the Oracle Database SQL Reference                                         |
+---------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since **RR** format element requires two digits for a year, but your source string has only one digit, 
so simply prepend `0` to the source string.

```
to_date(  '0' || source_string,  'RRDDD' )
```

Examples:

```
SELECT  
  to_date(  '0' || dd,  'RRDDD' )

FROM (
    SELECT '1234' dd FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '422' dd FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '9365' dd FROM dual
);

TO_DATE('0'||DD,'RRDDD')
------------------------
2001/08/22              
2004/01/22              
2009/12/31
```